# Redis with node: hgetall returns true, but callback returns null

Tags: node.js, redis

Brand new to redis, and I can't find the answer to what I am doing wrong.

I'm using redis to store some basic analytic info as middleware:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.path !== '/login') {
    const route = req.path
    const ip = req.ip
    const userId = req.userId
    const timestamp = new Date()
    client.hmset('HashKey', {
      'route': route,
      'ipAddress': ip,
      'userId': userId,
      'timestamp': timestamp
    })
  }

  console.log(client.hgetall('Hashkey') + '  ||  Hashkey')

  client.hgetall('Hashkey', function (err, results) {

    if (err) {
      return err
    } else {
      console.log(results + '  ||  Parsed Hashkey')
    }
  })
  next()
}
```

`console.log(client.hgetall('Hashkey') + '  ||  Hashkey')` returns true, which should indicate that there is an object in the database.  But `console.log(results + '  ||  Parsed Hashkey')` returns null.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:
Here is the initialization code:

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient({
  port: 6379
})
```

Comment: Which Redis library are you using & can share the Redis initialisation code also?

Comment: I'm using the npm redis library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).

Init is added above as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hmset` usually take and argument of an array like

```
client.hmset(["key", "test keys 1", "test val 1", "test keys 2", "test val 2"], function (err, res) {});
```

or

```
client.hmset("key", ["test keys 1", "test val 1", "test keys 2", "test val 2"], function (err, res) {});
```

or

```
client.hmset("key", "test keys 1", "test val 1", "test keys 2", "test val 2", function (err, res) {});
```

For your specific case use this

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient({
    port:6379,
    host:'localhost',
    db:1
});

const payload = {
    'route': 'my rrroute',
    'ipAddress': '127.0.0.1',
    'userId': 'asnim',
    'timestamp': new Date()
  };
  const redisValues = Object.keys(payload).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    accumulator.push(key);
    accumulator.push(payload[key]);
    return accumulator;
  }, []);

  client.hmset("Hashkey",redisValues, function (err, res) {});

  client.hgetall('Hashkey', function (err, results) {

    if (err) {
      return err
    } else {
      console.dir(results)
    }
  })

client.quit()
```

Ouput

```
{ route: 'my rrroute',
  ipAddress: '127.0.0.1',
  userId: 'asnim',
  timestamp: 'Wed Aug 21 2019 02:22:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
```

Comment: I tried all 3, and the got the same results each time--True for the hashkey, but null for the parsed values.  Out of curiosity, I added a callback to the `hmset` to see i that worked.  In all three syntaxes the `results` of the node style callback was `OK`

Comment: That still doesn't work.  I get True for the hashkey log statement, and null for the parsed values log statement.

Comment: It is a spelling mistake. You are setting the value Hash**K**ey and trying to retrieve from Hash**k**ey

Comment: Ah, that's really annoying.  I think you are right.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The redis library calls the database asynchronously. So there's no way this command `console.log(client.hgetall('Hashkey') + '  ||  Hashkey')` could have knowledge of the object existing within the database since the console.log statement is executed *before* the data is returned.

And so most likely your `results` is null because there isn't a 'HashKey' object in your database yet.